# How can I turn off "info" logging in browser console from HttpClients in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor WebAssembly client, I have this appsetting:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

So why do I still get endless cruft in my **browser console** when running locally?

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 190ms - 200 blazor.webassembly.js:1:9737
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 193ms - 200 blazor.webassembly.js:1:9737
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 267ms - 200 blazor.webassembly.js:1:9737
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 274ms - 200 blazor.webassembly.js:1:9737
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 316ms - 200 blazor.webassembly.js:1:9737
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyNamedClientName.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 319ms - 200
```

How can I turn off these info lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

...

builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
```

You have to configure the logger in the builder.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-configuration

Comment: This is in Program.cs on the Client, not the server, and that works well.

Comment: also add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration

Answer (score 11):

In a .NET 5 latest version in case you don't want those to be shown on blazor client side, you can do this in your Main method of startup class.

```
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 7):

How to remove the logging of HttpClient and nothing else:

```
builder.Services.RemoveAll<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You would better not set global minimal level.
And in Blazor WASM you won't find the extension method `AddConfiguration`.

Use this instead:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddFilter((category, level) =>
{
    return level >= LogLevel.Warning || !(category?.Contains("System.Net.Http.HttpClient") == true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for a specific **named** http client set in `Program.cs` of your Blazor WASM you can disable logging like that:

`builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApi").RemoveAllLoggers()`